# Calculate average of each line of input

Tags: c

I made a program that will loop and calculate the average of the input given by the user.
There are no problems here. I just want to know if there is a better way to do this, or a way to optimize this code.

#### How this program works:

First, the program will read a double and a separator in a forever loop until it finds a newline character or a wrong separator. If it finds a space as separator, then it will just continue to read more input. If it finds newline, then it will print the average. If it finds anything else separator, e.g. `'a'` or `'^'`, then it will print "error!".

#### The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double average, num, total;
    char separator;

    for(int i = 1; ; i++) //increment the value as the loop goes
    {
        scanf("%lf%c", &num, &separator);
        total += num;

        if(separator == '\n')
        {
            average = total / i;
            printf("average = %lf\n", average);
            break;
        }
        else if(separator == ' ')
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            while((getchar()) != '\n'); //clear buffer
            printf("error!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("press ENTER to exit...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we don't use any arguments, we could use `int main(void)` instead.

If we don't successfully read a number, `scanf` will return 0.  But we ignore that and use `num` anyway, indefinitely (since the input position is never advanced).

The scope of all the variables can be reduced to within the `for` loop.

`while((getchar()) != '\n');` will continue looping indefinitely if the input stream is closed (since `EOF != '\n'`).  Consider ignoring the rest of line with a single call to `scanf("%*[^\n]")` instead.  Alternatively, `return EXIT_FAILURE` to indicate the problem.

Error messages should go to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

The final `printf()` and `getchar()` make it harder to use your program as a filter in a pipe.  I would just drop them (and the `return 0;` that's implied by reaching the end of `main()`).

Answer (score 2):

the variable `total` is never initialized, then it is used as a source value in `total += num;` which results in undefined behavior.

the posted code does not re-initialize after the '\n' is processed znc your problem description fails to clarify what the proper action should be.

Comment: I read a website that default initializing for `int` is 0, so I just declare the variable without initialized it, as the first initialization would be just 0. Is it right?

Comment: btw, I don't understand about the undefined behavior, as my code seem to work without any problem(at least when I test it)